# Magento 2 order create programmatically use ideal payment method but not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods

I need payment method ideal and PayPal method set programmatically.
I have try many ways but still not working.
I have tried to cash on delivery it's working fine .but another payment method has try for that not wokring.
I have the following below link
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html

Thanks

Comment: Any error displaying?

Comment: No, Not any error is the display.

Comment: Check if paypal is enabled in Payement Method

Comment: Have you check that paypal is enabled?

Comment: yes  some other issue i was solved that issue.